# My iphone App got rejected with this reason "We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines,..."

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, ios5

My iphone app has got rejected recently & with below mentioned reason   :

"We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines."

**For this app I was storing database (sqlite file) in /Documents/ directory for iOS 5.0.1 & above & for iOS 5.0 & below versions I used Library/Cache directory.**

For other data like PDF & artwork images which I was downloading from server I followed the same approach as above like:
**iOS 5.0.1 & Later:** Saved these data into /Documents/ directory
**iOS 5.0 & earlier versions:** Saved data to Library/Cache directory.

Is this approach correct?

As per Apple guideline:
**Important**: The new "do not back up" attribute will only be used by iOS 5.0.1 or later. On iOS 5.0 and earlier, applications will need to store their data in /Library/Caches to avoid having it backed up. Since this attribute is ignored on older systems, you will need to insure your app complies with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines on all versions of iOS that your application supports.

Also very confused about that "do not back up" attribute assignment for the data stored for iOS 5.0.1 & later. For which files i need to assign this flag ? Can i use it for database?.

Need to get rid of these rejection as it has happened twice. Please provide some guidance for storing the data for my app. Thanks in advance. Looking forward for positive response.

Comment: You might try sending Marco Ament (of Instapaper a DM or a tweet). If I'm right he was dealing with this not too long ago. Any help this link - http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning   ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

specifically:

> Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to
>   persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your
>   app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use.
>   This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they
>   are in, including the Documents directory.

Store the SQLite db in the caches folder and set the donotbackup flag, which will stop the file being deleted by the cache clean system

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
}
```

I use a database in my app and store it in the cache folder (with the above flag set) and just got approved no problem.

In addition you can store your data in a subfolder of the documents directory, which I believe won't get backed up, but will persist.

Comment: Side re-iteration: be sure to use "com.apple.MobileBackup" not your own app bundle id.

Comment: What do you do if backup is a user requirement?

Comment: The page I linked to says it all, if it user generated content then it should go in /Documents WITHOUT the above flag set, that way it will be backed up to iCloud, anything else should go in /Library/Caches

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html In iOS 5.1 and later, store support files in the <Application_Home>/Library/Application Support directory... In iOS 5.0 and earlier, store support files in the <Application_Home>/Library/Caches directory

Answer (score 6):

One of my friend has the same problem. The basic problem is You might be storing heavy data in your Application document Directory.

After iCloud is implemented in Apple, The Document directory data is somehow related with iCloud Storage. Hence Apple is now rejecting the applications using heavy data storage in document directory.

You need to store the data at some other location. Store the PDF & Other Artwork file At some other location.

This link May Help You.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iOS_4_%28iPhone%29

I Hope it'll Solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To Solve Application rejected by Apple for your application does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, Please add following code in your application.

```
   - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
      if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) 
      {
            // iOS <= 5.0.1  
            const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];  
            const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";  
            u_int8_t attrValue = 1;  
            int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);  
            return result == 0;  
       } 
       else
        {
             // iOS >= 5.1  
             NSError *error = nil;  
            // if you set YES in Resources value then iTune will not backup that file or folder.
            //  You set FALSE in Resources value then iTune will backup that file or folder.
             [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];  
             return error == nil;
        } 
}
```

To Use this method (Example)

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CDTDatabaseNew" ofType:@"sqlite"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
NSURL *guidesURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbPath];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:guidesURL];
```

You have to use this method when you are create or copy files in Document directory.

NOTE :-Apple has changed the Data storage guide line and if you are storing anything in the Document directory then you have to right the above code, Don't miss this part of code.

App will be rejected if you don't put that code. So now onwards every one must have to add that pice of code when ever you create the database, store cached images, etc. in document directory.
Hope next time onwards I wan't get app rejected due to this reason.