# File read not accessable in device but on simulator

Tags: ios, path, afnetworking

I download the pdf file using afnetworking framework then to save file on this path.

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [NSBundle.mainBundle.resourceURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];
```

when i try to access the file using simulator. it works fine. but when to access on real device.

```
File at /var/mobile/Applications/40F3BDE0-F4B1-4C85-A32C-FEB08450646A/appname.app/file.pdf does not exist.
```

I think some sandboxing issue. but how to get rid of this issue. please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App's bundle is read only, you cannot save files to the bundle. Instead you could save it in apps `Documents` directory.

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}


NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.pdf"];
```

**Edit**
All the files in the `Documents` directory is sharable, that means other apps can access it. So if you put any data that cannot be viewable by the user dont put it documents instead use `Library` folder. Read more about [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: Now a days apple is rejecting the App, those are storing any file in Document directory as because now Document directory is sharable, so do it in Library Folder

Comment: why in case of simulator. it works! what fix it to be done in getting path?

Comment: @Janmenjaya I dont think. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @user3819810 Change the file writting path. It should not be app bundle

Comment: @AnilVarghese Please look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972378/app-rejected-due-to-data-in-documents-directory

This one too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767981/my-iphone-app-got-rejected-with-this-reason-we-found-that-your-app-does-not-fol

Comment: @Janmenjaya Thanks for the references. Apple is not preventing you from saving file to documents folder, only restriction is you should put only sharable or user viewable contents. That means you cannot store your app specific library here

Comment: @AnilVarghese BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Applications/D0724015-35C6-4B7C-8BAA-E66FBCCB2A71/Documents/OsGeo.pdf"]; this is check after changing method you did told above. but nothing change. still returns zero :(

Comment: So now you are writing to the documents folder? Can you check the writing was sucessful?

Comment: yes. during download no error ... and success callback of afnetworking executes

Comment: Check to where it is writing. Both paths are same or not

Comment: yes same. File downloaded to: /var/mobile/Applications/D0724015-35C6-4B7C-8BAA-E66FBCCB2A71/Documents/OsGeo.pdf

Comment: can you simply ans that. please. why the resource thing works in simulator case but not on real device! as you said "App's bundle is read only, you cannot save files to the bundle"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67549/discussion-between-user3819810-and-anil-varghese).